# PTX arrays as operands not working

Tags: arrays, cuda, ptx

The PTX manual (version 2.3) (http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/ptx_isa_2.3.pdf) 6.4.2 states:

> Array elements can be accessed using an explicitly calculated byte
>   address, or by indexing  into the array using square-bracket notation.
>   The expression within square brackets is either  a constant integer, a
>   register variable, or a simple “register with constant offset”
>   expression, where the offset is a constant expression that is either
>   added or subtracted from a register variable.  If more complicated
>   indexing is desired, it must be written as an address calculation
>   prior to use.

```
 ld.global.u32  s, a[0]; 
 ld.global.u32  s, a[N-1]; 
 mov.u32  s, a[1];  // move address of a[1] into s
```

When I try this I can only get the version pointer plus byte offset to work, i.e. `[a+0]`.

This code fails to load:

```
.reg    .f32 f<1>;
.global .f32 a[10];
ld.global.f32 f0,a[0];
```

Whereas this loads fine:

```
.reg    .f32 f<1>;
.global .f32 a[10];
ld.global.f32 f0,[a+0];
```

The problem with the byte offset version is that it really is a byte offset. So, one has to take the underlying size of the type into account, i.e. the second element is `[a+4]`. Whereas `a[1]` is supposed to work this out for you.

Ideas what's going wrong?

**EDIT**

And there is an even more severe issue here involved: The above text states that a register variable can be used to index the array, like:

```
ld.global.f32 f0,a[u0];
```

where `u0` is probably a `.reg.u32` or some other compatible integer.

However, with the pointer plus byte offset method this is not possible. It is illegal to do something like:

```
mul.u32 u1,u0,4;
ld.global.f32 f0,[a+u1]; // here a reg variable is not allowed.
```

Now this is a severe limitation. however, one can do another address calculation prior to the load statement. But this complicates things.

Comment: Your edit case wouldn't qualify as "register with constant offset". Both a and u1 are registers, neither is constant and could be evaluated at assemble time

Comment: That's exactly the point. If both are non-constant registers this is illegal. However if array indexing would work one could do neat things like `a[u0]`. At least this is what the manual says. You can get around to it via address precomputation but that complicates things. Any idea why the driver refuses to load `ld.global.f32 f0,a[0];` ?

Answer (score 1):

This does not seem to fit with the PTX documentation you quoted, but you can add in a multiplier corresponding with the size of the items in your array. For instance, to get the 10th 32-bit word:

```
ld.const.u32 my_u32, [my_ptr + 10 * 4];
```

Comment: I realized that since both 10 and 4 are constants in this case, the PTX assembler probably multiplies them. See if you can get some combination of register offset with multiplication working... I browsed through some compiler-generated PTX and the compiler seems to only use the byte offset method.